# What is the best free doctor practice management software?

Tags: diagnosis

What is the best free doctor practice management software in India where I can:

- Create diagnosis
- Book doctor appointments
- Upload reports

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [software recommendations are off-topic here](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/627/what-is-our-stance-on-questions-about-software-recommendations). You might consider re-asking this question over at [softwarerecs.se], but please make sure to look at [their help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first. Thank you.

Comment: Free? You expect decent practice management software to be free? Why would anyone spend the immense amount of time required to create something as complex as that and then just give it away?

Comment: @CareyGregory - While I understand (And agree as a programmer), many open source (i.e. free) software packages make very good money selling support packages for free software. Install, maintenance, etc. Also, many free EMR or similar type management software packages are free for basic items (Which might be suitable for a one doc practice), and then charge for extra packages (Metrics, things like that). Or the package is free for up to 50 patients, beyond that you have to pay.

Answer (score 1):

There are many websites which you can try but they are not free. The top 2 that you can checkout:

- [Practo](https://www.practo.com/)
- [Lybrate](https://www.lybrate.com/)

Here is a free practice management solution that I found:

- [Medariya](http://medariya.com/)

  You can:

  1. Create diagnosis
  2. Book doctor appointments
  3. Upload reports

Answer (score 0):

one of the better practice management solution which i have heard of is [Medariya](http://medariya.com/), they are fairly new but providing good features like EMR, appointment, scheduling, sms patients for booking and reminder. you should check it out.